# Spark as execution engine or spark as an application?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Which option is better to use, spark as an execution engine on hive or accessing hive tables using spark SQL? And Why?

Answer (score 0):

A few assumptions here are:

- Reason to opt for SQL is to stay user friendly, e.g. if you have business users trying to access data.
- Hive is in consideration because it provides an SQL like interface and persistence of data

If that is true, Spark-SQL is perhaps the better way forward. It is better integrated within Spark and as an integral part of Spark, it will provide more features (one example is structured streaming). You will still get user friendliness and an SQL like interface to Spark so you will get full benefits. But you will need to manage your system only from Spark's point of view. Hive installation and management will still be there but from a single perspective.

Using Hive with Spark as execution engine will keep you limited based upon how good a translation Hive's libraries are able to do to convert your HQL to Spark. They may do a pretty good job but you will still loose the advanced features of Spark SQL. And new features may take longer to get integrated in Hive compared to Spark SQL.

Also, with Hive exposed to end users, some advanced users or data engineering teams may want access to Spark. This will cause you to manage two tools. System management may get more tedious compared to only using Spark-SQL in this scenario as Spark SQL has the potential to serve both non-technical and advanced users and even if advanced users use pyspark, spark-shell or more, they will still be integrated within the same toolset.